# Send keys issue in copy static text and pasting it via Send key

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to copy a static text from `Send Keys` and pasting the same via `Send Keys, I am not able to copy that text and paste it, instead it is pasting the value which i have copied previously.

```
    Set a = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    a.SendKeys("^c ABC")
    a.SendKeys("^v")
```

I want to paste the text "ABC" to my hardship it is pasting the value which i copied previously for e.g. "XYZ" instead of "ABC" after the code run.

I also tried to send the direct content but no help.

```
a.Sendkeys("ABC")
```

Please let me know where i am wrong in this. Thanks

Comment: From where did you get this information that `a.SendKeys("^c ABC")` will copy `ABC` to clipboard?

Comment: Look at `a.AppActivate <windowname>` command.

Comment: @gurman : I was experimenting, as i have no experience of `Sendkeys` properities and Methods :(. @ACatInLove : I am working with a Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using mercury object and clearing the values initially copied. Please refer to the below code-

```
Set objCB = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard")
objCB.clear
functionForSendKey("^c")
wait(1)
```